# highcharts mapbubble display 3 times

Tags: javascript, r, charts, highcharts, maps

I made this map with highcharter package (for R) which is a highcharts wrapper but there are still 3 bubbleLegend and I only want one of them

If anyone can help me, maybe in js?
There's even a commit that fixed the issue here in js : https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/63dc48767b3aa00b846631084b286f6605342e22

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

mydf <- data.frame(
  lat = c(-7.1871, 36.95733, 17.9356, -20.4379, 30.2496, -54.9593,
          18.0365, 17.9688, 18, 18.005, 17.9538),
  lon = c(129.3989, -121.576, -66.6961, -68.773, 138.6162, -128.3548,
          -66.8143, -66.9705, -66.7603, -66.7765, -66.8265),
  z = c(4.5, 2.77, 4.1, 5.2, 4.5, 5.1, 2.52, 3.7, 2.68, 2.71, 2.88),
  part = c(10,15,8,20,30,12,5,17,21,9,11)
)

mydf <- mydf %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(
    part < 10 ~ "red",
    part < 20 ~ "green",
    TRUE ~ "blue"
  ))

hcmap() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = mydf, type = "mapbubble", name = "EarthQuake", maxSize = '12%') %>% 
  hc_tooltip(useHTML = T,headerFormat='',pointFormat = paste('Location :{point.place}<br> Part: {point.part} <br> Magnitude : {point.z}')) %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = TRUE,
            title = list(text = "Mon titre"),
            bubbleLegend = list(
              enabled = TRUE,
              borderColor = '#000000',
              borderWidth = 3,
              color = '#8bbc21',
              connectorColor = '#000000',
              sizeBy = "z",
              ranges = list(
                list(
                  value = 100
                  )
                ,
                list(
                  value=70
                ),
                list(
                  value= 40
                ),
                list(
                  value= 10
                )
              )
            ),
            align = "bottom", layout = "horizontal",
            floating = TRUE ,valueDecimals = 0,
            symbolHeight = 11, symbolWidth = 11, symbolRadius = 0) %>%
  hc_colorAxis(
    dataClasses = color_classes(breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 100),
                                colors = c("red","green","blue")
    )) %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Global Seismic Activity") %>% 
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = T)%>% 
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you gave a link to was fixed and merged into the library in February 2019. In my environment, I have installed Highcharter that uses Highcharts `7.2.0` which was released in September 2019. https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/

The fix is included and it works fine in my environment. I can see only 1 bubble legend.

[image]

**You should make sure that you are using the latest version of Highcharter.** You can check the version by right mouse button clicking on chart, then `Inspect element`

[image]

and then find the version here

[image]

Let me know which one are you using.

Comment: "Created with Highcharts 7.0.1" yet I'm using the latest version of highcharter (0.7.0). So does that mean I have to wait for highcharter to support highcharts 7.2.0?

Comment: Could you tell me which version of highcharter did you use ?

Comment: So you have the answer ;) 7.0.1 is from 2018, that's why you have 3 bubble legends.
I don't know how, but you should update your highcharter somehow. Maybe uninstall the package and install it again.

Comment: How can I check the highcharter version?

Comment: here https://pasteboard.co/J8b1F2m.png I'll try to uninstall/install

Comment: Ok it works ! I installed the CRAN version instead of the dev version on github... Many thanks !